# How can C# textbox values be written into a Typed Collection?

Tags: c#, .net

My objective is to pass values from a Windows Form `TextBox` control into a Typed Collection of type `double` so I can perform arithmetic operations on the values in the collection.  Eventually, I will convert the `double`s to `string` and write them out to a `MessageBox`.
The windows form has three `button`s; Submit, Display, and Close.

Submit will take the values, such as `4`, `10.5`, and write them into a Typed Collection.  The Collection needs to be a `double`.  I defined it as follows: `List<Double>  dNumbers  = new List<Double>();`

Do I need to create a Collection of type `string` and cycle through the values in the `TextBox` and write them into the `string` Collection, and then convert them into the collection of type `double`?

I'm sorry I do not have any code to share since it is all syntactically incorrect and generates conversion errors. Should I zip the application and attach it?  Any help is appreciated.

I am using .NET version 4.5

Thank you for all the replies. I have no professional programming experience, and I am attempting to learn .Net with C# and all its nuances so thank you for your patience. I am also new to Stack Overflow and am learning the Q and A protocol. Here is the Display Event Handler.

public void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(dNumbers.Count), "dNumbers List Count");
        foreach (double dNum in dNumbers)
        {
            txtDisplayValues.Text += dNum + " ";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show what code you have, even if it doesn't compile.  Do not ZIP up the project and add as an attachment.

Comment: Why do you need a collection?  Seems like you could do it with two variables.

Comment: Why not just use the `Double.Parse(String s)` method to do the conversion for you?

Comment: We need what you have so far so that we can pattern our answers off of what you want correctly.

Comment: Also, how are the numbers separated in the textbox? By commas, spaces, ...

Comment: @DStanley: The purpose of using a collection, as opposed to using two variables, was to provide the user the ability to enter more than one or two values. Perhaps there is a better method by which the user may enter multiple values than what I have outlined.

Comment: @BalinKingOfMoria: The values are separated by spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to:
 - Enter in the TextBox double values like 4.5 10.5 22.5 ans so on
 - Save each individual value in a list of double values

Do the following:
 - Split the string in the text box to get all individual double
   values, using   Split method in Regex class in
   System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace.   This will result in a
   string array.

-Loop through this array, convert each string to double and add it to the list.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
.......

private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

  // Step 1- split the string after each blank space
  string[] numbersInTextBox = Regex.Split(textBox.Text, @" ");

  //Step 2 - convert to double and add to the list
  foreach (string strNumber in numbersInTextBox)
  {
           double dNumber = Convert.ToDouble(strNumber);
           dNumbers.Add(dNumber);
  }

}
```

Comment: You can also use double  dNumber = double.Parse(strNumber)   instead of Convert class. Be aware that if a user enters something else than double values, or 2 blank spaces we will get errors. Se you have to implement Exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

Slapshot,

If you have only two numbers I cannot see a reason for using a List or some other collections to keep them. According to your explanation of the problem I think something like the following code will help you achieve :

```
private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

  // Try to parse the numbers
  double  numberOne, numberTwo;
  bool isTextOneNumber = Double.TryParse(text1.Text, out numberOne);
  bool isTextTwoNumber = Double.TryParse(text2.Text, out numberTwo);
  if(isTextOneNumber && isTextTwoNumber )
  {
     //calculate what you want with numberOne, numberTwo
  }
  else
  {
    //provide some error(validation) message
  }
}
```

Comment: The OP did not specify there would be two numbers exactly.